# PHP match comma separated string with array value but not in exact order

Tags: php, arrays, explode, strpos, array-intersect

I have a possibly simple query but couldn't find an exact solution anywhere.

There is a comma separated string such as **1,3** and an array with values such as **1,3,2** OR **3,1,4**. I need a function that when I try to search this string in the array, it returns TRUE for both the records as the number 1 & 3 exists in both array values but just in different order.

I have tried using `array_search`, `strpos` and even `explode` to first make the string in an array followed by `array_intersect` to intersect both arrays hoping to get a positive match but always only returns the array with values 1,3,2 and not 3,1,4.

Any suggestions or pointers would be extremely helpful.

Many thanks in advance.

======================

PS: Here's my code

```
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!
$st_array = array();
$st_data1['id'] = 1;
$st_data1['title'] = 'Jane doe';
$st_data1['disk'] = '1,3,2';
array_push($st_array, $st_data1);

$rc_disk_id = '1,3';

$st_data2['id'] = 2;
$st_data2['title'] = 'Jane Smith';
$st_data2['disk'] = '3,1,4';
array_push($st_array, $st_data2);


foreach($st_array as $st_data) {
    $rc_disk_ids = explode(",",$rc_disk_id);
    $match = array_intersect($rc_disk_ids, $st_data);
    if (!empty($match)) {
        echo "\nFound\n";
        print_r($st_data);
    }
    else {
        echo "Nope!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very close. You need to also [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the list of disk ids in `$st_data`, and then use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to check whether *all* of the values in `$rc_disk_ids` are present in that list:

```
foreach($st_array as $st_data) {
    $rc_disk_ids = explode(",",$rc_disk_id);
    $st_disk_ids = explode(',', $st_data['disk']);
    $match = array_diff($rc_disk_ids, $st_disk_ids);
    if (empty($match)) {
        echo "\nFound\n";
        print_r($st_data);
    }
    else {
        echo "Nope!";
    }
}
```

Output for your sample data:

```
Found
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [title] => Jane doe
    [disk] => 1,3,2
)

Found
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [title] => Jane Smith
    [disk] => 3,1,4
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9JhFQ)

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I wanted. That worked exactly, no matter the order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try searching for the string instead of comparing arrays.

```
$strArr = explode(",", "1,3");
$arrToBeSearched = ["1", "3", "2"];

foreach($strArr as $val){
    if(!in_array($val, $arrToBeSearched)){
        return FALSE;
    }
}

// If it reaches here, then all values in 
//the $strArr where found in the 
//$arrToBeSearched
return TRUE;
```

Comment: See below. @Nick 's solution gives me exactly what I want. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user7616631 Yeah I saw that, just hopefully another way to the same solution. I'm on mobile so I can't test the code, but either way I hope you get the general idea